# C++ What's a way to access an array struct using a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

So I have two functions. One find the max number of an array located inside a struct. The second one finds the largest number in an array of the struct above.

Struct

```
struct ABC {
    unsigned n;
    char c;
    double a[3];
};
```

First function

```
double max(const ABC & x) {
    double largest = x.a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (largest < x.a[i])
            largest = x.a[i];
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Second function and the one I'm having trouble with.

```
double max(const ABC arr[], unsigned elements) {
    double largest = 0;
    cout << largest << endl;
    if (elements == 0)
        terminate("You need more than 1 element");
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {

        largest = max(ABC(arr[i])));
        if (largest <= max(ABC(arr[i])));
        {
            largest = max(ABC(arr[i]));
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

This is what I'm calling on the main functions:

```
const unsigned els = 4;
ABC arr[els];
arr[0] = { 1, 'a',{ 19.0, 20.0, 3.0 } };
arr[1] = { 2, 'b',{ 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 } };
arr[2] = { 3, 'c',{ 7.0, 80.0, 9.0 } };
arr[3] = { 4, 'd',{ 10.0, 11.0, 7.0 } };
largest = max(arr, els);
```

The max function should be returning the max value of those arrays, but I get 11 instead. I did some testing and figured that the problem came when calling the max function inside of the loop of the second function. Does anybody know why that is?

How do I make the first max function work with the second function?

Note: This is an assignment, It's a small part of 20 other functions I had to write; however, I'm not asking people to solve it for me, all I'm asking to know is how I could use the first function with the second one. I don't consider that cheating, I just need help with something minor.

In short, the problem I'm having is that when I call the `max(ABC(arr[0])))` and set the 0 to a number greater than 0 I get 11 as the max value. Why is that happening?

Comment: I smell homework....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
{

    largest = max(ABC(arr[i])));
    if (largest <= max(ABC(arr[i])));
    {
        largest = max(ABC(arr[i]));
    }
}
```

You're resetting `largest` on every iteration! That's why only the last array element is counting.

Presumably it's just a typo and you meant to go straight into the conditional.

By the way, those repeated calls to `max` are not very efficient, and I don't see the purpose in casting the object `arr[i]` into a `ABC` copy.

Why not this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    const double this_max = max(arr[i]);
    if (largest <= this_max)
       largest = this_max;
}
```

*(I swapped your `int` to `size_t` so that you're not comparing signed and unsigned integers. Didn't your compiler warn you about this?)*

Comment: @WillBriggs: Yeah like an hour and a half ago :P

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
largest = max(ABC(arr[i]));
```

from the for-loop.

When you have it inside the for-loop, you reset largest to the *latest* max every time.

Comment: Oh go on have an upvote anyway. You're so close to 1,000 rep!